# Iterating over dict RDD and assign value to dataframe column

Tags: python, pyspark

So I have a dataframe `df` like so,

```
+---+-----+
| ID|COL_A|
+---+-----+
|  1|  123|
+---+-----+
```

I also have a dict like so:

```
{"COL_B":"abc","COL_C":""}
```

Now, what I have to do is to update df with keys in dict being the new column name and the value of key being the costant value of the column.

Expected df should be like:

```
+---+-----+-----+-----+
| ID|COL_A|COL_B|COL_C|
+---+-----+-----+-----+
|  1|  123|  abc|     |
+---+-----+-----+-----+
```

Now here's my python code to do it which is working fine...

```
input_data = pd.read_csv(inputFilePath,dtype=str)
for key, value in mapRow.iteritems():   #mapRow is the dict
        if value is None:
                input_data[key] = ""
        else:
                input_data[key] = value
```

**Now I'm migrating this code to pyspark and would like to know how to do it in pyspark**?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: if both will be RDD then you will be basically joining them, using `join`, `map` or `zip`

Comment: @UpasanaMittal: would you mind elaborating a bit on that. I'm kind of new to pyspark

Answer (score 0):

To combine RDDs, we use use `zip` or `join` . Below is the explanation using `zip`. `zip` is to concat them and `map` to flatten.

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

rdd_1 = sc.parallelize([Row(ID=1,COL_A=2)])
rdd_2 = sc.parallelize([Row(COL_B="abc",COL_C=" ")])

result_rdd = rdd_1.zip(rdd_2).map(lamda x: [j for i in x for j in i])
```

**NOTE** I didn't have payspark currently with me so this isn't tested.